# Can I give drivers to objects in batches?

Tags: objects, drivers

Can I give drivers to objects in batches, just like link materials or copy modifiers?

[image]

Comment: Ctrl-L > Link Animation Data maybe? Or you can right-click on the field with the driver > Copy driver, then select your other object and Right-click > Paste Driver into the same field.

Comment: @John Eason Thanks, it is feasible to link animation data, but it seems that the paste drive can't be copied in batches. Is to hold down the Alt to operate? But it's enough for me to continue my work. Thank you again!

Comment: I'm not sure if the Alt key would work in that case because I've never tried it to be honest, but it's worth trying with a test setup. Just make sure that all the objects you want to receive the copied driver are selected before pasting the driver.

Answer (score 0):

Select all objects with your object having driver as your active selection. Then go to object drop down menu-constraints-copy to selected.